# Custom UITableViewCell from a .xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom UITableViewCell from a .xib file

In the ViewController where I have the UITableView I already did the following:

Ctrl + Drag the tableViewDataSource and the tableViewDelegate to this View Controller in the Interface Builder.

And this code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ResultsFoundViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.tableView.dataSource = self;
            self.tableView.delegate = self;

       //Register my Custom Cell
            let customCellName = String(describing: ResultsFoundTableViewCell.self);
            let customCellNib = UINib.init(nibName: customCellName, bundle: nil);
            self.tableView.register(customCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: customCellName);
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5;
        }

        // MARK: UITableViewDataSource Functions

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ResultsFoundTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ResultsFoundTableViewCell;
            cell.lbStoreName.text = "Name";

    return cell;
            } 
}
```

In the CustomCell I only have a label to make it simpler:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsFoundTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbStoreName: UILabel! 
}
```

The error I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered
>   for identifier (ResultsFoundTableViewCell) - nib must contain exactly
>   one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'

Do you know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this problem is that you must put all your UI components inside the **cell->contentView** , if any element is out of it , the nib registration will fail

Also make nib declaration without Describting

```
    let customCellNib = UINib.init(nibName: "nibClassName", bundle: nil);
    self.tableView.register(customCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: customCellName);
```

As `String(describing` here

```
  let customCellName = String(describing: ResultsFoundTableViewCell.self);
```

adds optional to  string content like this Optional("nibClassName")

Comment: Okay, there was an element somewhere outside the cell, haven't seen it. Thanks for that!

About the nib declaration: What if I don't want to type the "nibClassName" and get it automatically from the class name as I'm doing now? So in case I change it or I don't write it correctly it will still work.

Comment: it's benefit when nib name is not same as class name , but in most cases they're same and it's good to go